# What is a regex to add text in the right place of a string that contains multiple matching paranthesis?

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

When fixing a `null` variable error that is passed to `htmlspecialchars` function, I want to add an empty string as a fall-back.

Example:

```
$var = null;
htmlspecialchars($var); // error, no null allowed

// error suppressed because function receives an (empty) string, which is not null
htmlspecialchars($var ?? '');
```

**Basic Regex**

I wrote a regex that appears to work correctly when there is only one set of parenthesis that belongs to the function itsef:

Find: `(htmlspecialchars\([^\)]*)(\))`

Replace with: `\1 ?? ''\2`

Here regex matches `htmlspecialchars($var);`
And replaces it with `htmlspecialchars($var ?? '');`

**Question**

What is a regex that can be used to correctly add the  `?? ''` text before the last parenthesis that belongs to the htmlspecialchars function itself?

Example input text I have

```
htmlspecialchars($var)?>" />
htmlspecialchars(date('m/d/Y'))?>" /></td>
htmlspecialchars(json_encode($config))?>" />
htmlspecialchars(addslashes(get_office_name($office_id))) . "'); ";
```

Example output text I want:

```
htmlspecialchars($var ?? '')?>" />
htmlspecialchars(date('m/d/Y') ?? '')?>" /></td>
htmlspecialchars(json_encode($config) ?? '')?>" />
htmlspecialchars(addslashes(get_office_name($office_id)) ?? '') . "'); ";
```

Comment: You can do this in PCRE and equivalent regex flavours by recursively matching balanced parentheses. For example, search for `(?(DEFINE)(?'function'\w+\((?:[^()]+|(?P>function))\)))htmlspecialchars\((?:(?P>function)|[^()]+)\K` and replace by ` ?? ''`. See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zq77Xz/1).

Comment: Without recursion for up to three levels of nesting try [this pattern](https://regex101.com/r/Ok9903/1) and replace with `\1 ?? '')`.

Comment: bobble, that worked, thanks!  What concept did you use?

Answer (score 1):

I am using vscode here and we replace with `$1`,`$2`, etc but I noticed that you may be replacing with `\1`,`\2`, etc so do as it applies to you.

Match with `(htmlspecialchars\([^\)]*)(\))?(\))?(\))`
and replace with this `\1\2\3 ?? ''\4`

or this `$1$2$3 ?? ''$4` (for vscode users)